# Using externally defined component with Vue and TypeScript class decorator syntax

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

I'm trying to consume [`vue-form-wizard`](https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/) in a Vue component, using the TypeScript decorator syntax enabled by [`vue-class-component`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component).

Here is my `.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <form-wizard>
        <tab-content title="Personal details">
            My first tab content
        </tab-content>
        <tab-content title="Additional Info">
            My second tab content
        </tab-content>
        <tab-content title="Last step">
            Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
        </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import { FormWizard, TabContent} from "vue-form-wizard";

@Component({
    components: {
        FormWizard, TabContent
    }
})
export default class AdvisorWizard extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

And here is the error TypeScript generates:

> ```
> Argument of type '{ components: { FormWizard: typeof FormWizard; TabContent: typeof TabContent; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'components' does not exist in type 'VueClass<Vue>'. Did you mean to write 'component'?
> ```

I'm pretty sure that this is because `FormWizard` doesn't extend or otherwise implement Vue.  But I can't figure out how to cast the component or otherwise coerce TypeScript into believing that `FormWizard` is a Vue component.

Is it possible that the typings for `FormWizard` are just wrong?

```
export type ShapeType = 'circle' | 'square' | 'tab'
export type LayoutType = 'vertical' | 'horizontal'
export type StepSizeType = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'

export declare class Wizard {
  /** Wizard title */
  title: string
  /** Wizard subtitle */
  subtitle: string
  nextButtonText: string
  backButtonText: string
  finishButtonText: string
  /** Whether to hide footer buttons */
  hideButtons: boolean
  /** Whether to trigger beforeChange function when navigating back */
  validateOnBack: boolean
  /** Active step and button color */
  color: string
  /** Step color when the current step is not valid */
  errorColor: string
  /** Main step shape */
  shape: ShapeType
  /** Wizard layout */
  layout: LayoutType
  /** Additional css classes for steps */
  stepsClasses: string[]
  /** Step size */
  stepSize: StepSizeType
  /** Step transition from inactive to active */
  transition: string
  /** Tab index where the wizard should start */
  startIndex: number
}
```

If so, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The type definitions in `vue-form-wizard` were [updated to address this problem](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard/pull/289), but never released. You can manually install the GitHub commit that includes the changes, using this command:

```
npm i -S git://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard#c686975
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to install the version of vue-form-wizard that you pointed to and reading through the type declarations & exports it sure seems like FormWizard and TabContent extend Vue.  But I am still getting the exact same error.  Any thoughts on what else I might be doing?

Comment: @DavidWGray Hmm. Do you have a GitHub link I can look at to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I stand corrected.  This does work.  Apparently, something was being cached inappropriately.  I copied my project to create a minimum reproducible case to upload to github, opened it in vscode and the error was gone. Then I just tried reloading vscode on the original project and things worked there.  So I'm set.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidWGray No problem :)